# magento check if product value contains a specific word

Tags: php, magento

Working with magento I have a custom option for a product which has rows with a date and then a location as it's title. For example the options could be: *

- 29th October - London,
- 26th November - Leeds,
- 28th November -
  London.

Is it possible to write an if else statement based on just part of the custom option's title value?

for example

```
<?php if($value == "Leeds"): ?>
Content
<?php else : ?>
other content 
<?php endif : ?>
```

Also, how to I call the custom option values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/functionContentatch.php)

```
$mystring = '6th November - Leeds';
$findme   = 'Leeds';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

if ($pos !== false) {
     // Content
} else {
     // other content
}
```

Comment: I was going to go down the `explode ("-", $sku);` route but will also look at stropos. Thank you